# Why doesn't this recursive javascript function return the correct value

Tags: javascript, recursion

Why does this function return `undefined`?

The interior function returns the correct value.

```
function arraySum(i) {

    // i will be an array, containing integers, strings and/or arrays like itself.
    // Sum all the integers you find, anywhere in the nest of arrays.

    (function (s, y) {
        if (!y || y.length < 1) {
            //console.log(s);
            // s is the correct value
            return s;
        } else {
            arguments.callee(s + y[0], y.slice(1));
        }
    })(0, i);
}

var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arraySum(x);
```

Comment: You don't return `arguments.callee(...)`.

Comment: OK, so I rewrote it with a named function and now it's working.    `function arraySum(i) {

    function acc (s, y) {
        if (!y || y.length < 1) {
            //console.log(s);
            // s is the correct value
            return s;
        } else {
            return acc(s + y[0], y.slice(1));
        }


    }

return acc(0,i);
}


var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(arraySum(x));`

Comment: I recommend not using `arguments.callee` or `arguments.caller`; it will be removed in ECMAScript 6, and is already not available in ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode.

Comment: _"OK, so I rewrote it with a named function and now it's working"_ - Yes, but it works more because you added the missing `return` keyword in two places than because you introduced a function name. In any case, if you've figured out a solution you should post it as an answer - it's acceptable here at StackOverflow to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you said in the code's comment is true, this is what you need.

```
function arraySum(i) {

    // i will be an array, containing integers, strings and/or arrays like itself
    // Sum all the integers you find, anywhere in the nest of arrays.

    return (function (s, y) {
        if (y instanceof Array && y.length !== 0) {
            return arguments.callee(arguments.callee(s, y[0]), y.slice(1));
        } else if (typeof y === 'number') {
            return s + y;
        } else {
            return s;
        }
    })(0, i);
}
```

**Output**

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(arraySum(x));
x = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]];
console.log(arraySum(x));
x = [1, "2", 2, [3, 4, 5]];
console.log(arraySum(x));
x = [1, "2", [2, [3, 4, 5]]];
console.log(arraySum(x));
```

Comment: I should have removed those comments. That's the part of the quiz I was still working on.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
return arguments.callee( s + y[0], y.slice(1))
```

Or just use reduce :-) :

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce( function(sum, x) { return sum + x; }, 0 );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: A `return` is also needed before the IIFE. `return (function (s, y) {...`

Comment: Why do you pass a second argument to reduce? It is unnecessary.

Comment: It's the initial value to pass to the first arg to the callback.  It's for clarity.