# How can I return the searched value inside a loop in a recursive function?

Tags: javascript

Given the following array of objects acting as a tree of nodes

```
const tree = [
  {
    label: "Gilfoyle",
    data: 160,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Nami",
    data: 171,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Root",
    data: 172,
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        label: "Root child 1",
        data: 174,
        expanded: true,
        children: [
          {
            label: "Root child 2",
            data: 175,
            expanded: true,
            children: [
              {
                label: "Root child 3",
                data: 176,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{}],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "sk3wl 0f r00t",
    data: 159,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Collection",
    data: 166,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Compass",
    data: 165,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Sample",
    data: 17,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "School of root",
    data: 18,
    children: [],
  },
];
```

I need to get one of these objects by its id

To this end, the following function loops through each node and compares the value of the data property with the id of the searched node.

```
function getNode(tree, id) {
  if (tree && Array.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for (const node of tree) {
      if (node.data === id) {
        console.dir(node, { depth: null });
        return node;
        break;
      }

      getNode(node.children, id);
    }
  }
}
```

The node is found as can be seen in the following snippet. But I require the function to return the node.

```js
const tree = [
  {
    label: "Gilfoyle",
    data: 160,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Nami",
    data: 171,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Root",
    data: 172,
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        label: "Root child 1",
        data: 174,
        expanded: true,
        children: [
          {
            label: "Root child 2",
            data: 175,
            expanded: true,
            children: [
              {
                label: "Root child 3",
                data: 176,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{}],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "sk3wl 0f r00t",
    data: 159,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Collection",
    data: 166,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Compass",
    data: 165,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Sample",
    data: 17,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "School of root",
    data: 18,
    children: [],
  },
];

function getNode(tree, id) {
  if (tree && Array.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for (const node of tree) {
      if (node.data === id) {
        console.dir(node, { depth: null });
        return node;
        break;
      }

      getNode(node.children, id);
    }
  }
}

const output = getNode(tree, 176);

console.dir(output, { depth: null });
```

I have confirmed that it only returns the node if the search id is the last element of the list. In the other cases, as in the example, the snippet returns undefined

How can I return the searched value inside a loop in a recursive function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't this recursive javascript function return the correct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204761/why-doesnt-this-recursive-javascript-function-return-the-correct-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick (and admittedly a little dirty) way is to just check if a value was found by `getNode`:

```js
const tree = [
  {
    label: "Gilfoyle",
    data: 160,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Nami",
    data: 171,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Root",
    data: 172,
    expanded: true,
    children: [
      {
        label: "Root child 1",
        data: 174,
        expanded: true,
        children: [
          {
            label: "Root child 2",
            data: 175,
            expanded: true,
            children: [
              {
                label: "Root child 3",
                data: 176,
                expanded: false,
                children: [{}],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "sk3wl 0f r00t",
    data: 159,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Collection",
    data: 166,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Compass",
    data: 165,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "Sample",
    data: 17,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "School of root",
    data: 18,
    children: [],
  },
];

function getNode(tree, id) {
  if (tree && Array.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for (const node of tree) {
      if (node.data === id) {
        console.dir(node, { depth: null });
        return node;
        break;
      }

      const found = getNode(node.children, id);

      if (found) return found;
    }
  }
}

const output = getNode(tree, 176);

console.dir(output, { depth: null });
```

Comment: Works. Out of curiosity. Why do you think it's a little dirty solution?

Comment: It's not the cleanest. You should try to go for either a return statement at the end of the recursive function, or make the return statement the only statement in the body for the "cleanest" (but not always the best).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the reply. Recursion is usually a mess for me. I appreciate the assistance